# Any good Emgu.CV.Maui For Object Detection Examples?

Tags: maui

I am trying to use Emgu.Cv.maui.mini in .Net Maui for the real-time object detection but their example is not working.

I am Also try another Plugins but not anyone working

So anyone have use it point me to examples of Emgu.CV.Maui for real-time object detection